# UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>.pointee always gives the same value while reading an image in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, unsafemutablepointer

i have the following code, i am trying to ready the image i have in order to define where is the white pixels, transparent and so on, but my output always is 255 ( if (pointer.pointee >> 24) == 255) so it is telling me that it is all black, while it's not!
any help?

```
    var colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let imageCG = image.cgImage!
    imageWidth = imageCG.width
    imageHeight = imageCG.height
    imageScale = image.scale
    totalPixels = imageHeight * imageWidth

    var bitsPerComponent = 8
    var bytesPerRow = 4 * imageWidth
    var bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Little.rawValue | CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue

    // Init imageContext
    imageContext = CGContext(data: nil, width: imageWidth, height: imageHeight, bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponen`enter code here`t, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo)!
    imageContext.draw(imageCG, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageWidth, height: imageHeight))


    // Init imageData

    imageData = imageContext.data!.bindMemory(to: UInt32.self, capacity: totalPixels)

    // Init regionsData
    regionsData = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt16>.allocate(capacity: totalPixels)

    var regionsPointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt16> = regionsData
    var pointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32> = imageData

    // Scan image data and mark full transparent, semitransparent and opaque pixels in regions data

    let minAlpha = UInt32(255 - transparencyTolerance)

    for _ in 0..<totalPixels {
        if (pointer.pointee >> 24) == 255 {
            regionsPointer.pointee = regionsBlackColor
        } else if (pointer.pointee >> 24) > minAlpha {
            regionsPointer.pointee = regionsTransparentColor
        } else {
            regionsPointer.pointee = regionsWhiteColor
        }
        pointer.pointee = whiteColor
        pointer = pointer.successor()
        regionsPointer = regionsPointer.successor()
    }
```

Comment: An alpha value of 255 doesn't mean black, it just means opaque. You need to look at the RGB values to work out if a given pixel is black or not.

Comment: thanks for your response, but my problem is that it is always returning 255(no matter what 255 means), whay am i always getting the same value even though i am going through all the pixels in my image?

Comment: Is your image opaque?

Comment: no it's not, it is something like this, if u can access this link:
http://dg7csqkdaad2n.cloudfront.net/Media/1429252235684_1494856119.png

Comment: That image *is* opaque – it has a solid white background.

Comment: so when if i change it to transparent, my code should work? thanks, i'll give it a try as soon as i can

Comment: problem solved thanks